# Does Siri get better if I use it more?

Tags: siri, voice-dictation, voice-recognition

There are a number of post on the internet arguing that Siri might be better if Apple would not value privacy so much. Other say that this is not necessarily true.<sup>1,2</sup>

Assuming, that apple does respect my privacy I am wondering how Siri (on my mac, my iPad, my iPhone *etc.*) does actually *learn*.
Do I need to dictate to Siri (and correct all the blue under lined words)? Does Siri get better over time and if so is that a cloud improvement for my Apple ID or something localized to the learning on each device as it learns?

[1]: [www.fastcompany.com](https://www.fastcompany.com/40443055/apple-explains-how-its-making-siri-smart-without-endangering-user-privacy)
[2]: [www.cnet.com](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-will-keep-conversations-with-siri-and-homepod-a-secret/)

Comment: Interesting - I've seen no evidence that Siri adapts to me, but that I'm adapting to Siri. It will be interesting if there's any empirical evidence people can report to reverse engineer this. Since Siri is clearly under active development and changing all the time that complicates things, but even picking one point in time - there might be something more than speculation / opinion / rumor that can be stated.

Comment: I agree with bmike, there is very little chance of getting anything more than speculation here, the only thing Apple has said is that it does learn, I can say from my experience that it is better at voice recognition now than it was a few years ago, but I think that learning applies to all users, not just me.